Microsoft Graph DOCX to PDF not processing fields, is there a way?
When opening the DOCX locally (Word), then saving it to PDF, all fields get processed/updated automatically and the PDF generated is correct.
When using Microsoft Graph API to convert the exact same DOCX file in Sharepoint to PDF, the generated PDF does not have fields processed (for example, page number references show as zero instead of the expected page number).
I don't see an option in Microsoft Graph API to generate PDF like Word does, processing all fields during conversion.
I also don't see that limitation in Microsoft Graph API documentation.
I found a similar complaint from 2021: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/using-microsoft-graph-api-to-convert-the-format-of-your/bc-p/2865292/highlight/true#M5973
Is there a way to make Microsoft Graph API process fields, or do I really need to look for another way to convert DOCX to PDF online?
